# Is it ever possible to "sell" the right to action a tort?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-law, common-law, any-jurisdiction

Suppose Bob discriminates against Alice on a date 1/1/2023. Alice has a right to sue Bob for this discrimination for some limited period, but she doesn't care to bother with the hassle of pursuing this compensation. Charles, not having been a victim of Bob's discriminatory conduct, would have no right to pursue Bob for such compensation. But can Alice in any way "sell," "transfer" or "assign" her standing in the matter to Charles, so that he may pursue whatever the court would have awarded to Alice in his own right, and in her lieu?

Comment: This is similar to the way a [Claims Management Company](https://www.fca.org.uk/consumers/using-claims-management-companies) operates

Comment: @Rick Although is it not the case that such companies still ultimately represent you, and act on your behalf? You haven't transferred or assigned anything; you've merely employed them to handle the case for you.

Comment: Hence *similar*

Comment: @Rick yes but then I think I would argue that its actually not all that similar.